# There are two circle in my xamarin form drawing using drawing using skiasharp. How can I put different touch event handler on both of this circle?

Tags: xamarin.forms, touch-event, skiasharp

I am trying to set different touch event on the circle drawing using skiasharp on my xamarin form. How can I do so? Is there any Id like android studio that I can use to track which circle am I pressing?

Comment: use basic math to determine if point X is in circle A or circle B

Comment: @Jason Do you have any examples for me to refer? Or do you have other ways to do it instead of adding event handler on the circle?